# multiple table joins in MYSQL affects performance issue

Tags: mysql, join

As in MySQL if we are using joins in multiple tables, it takes time to get data, which affects the performance. Any alternative for this, or solution for this?

as we have a view and procedure available. please let me know that provides same result as joins but with better performance.

Comment: Add appropriate indices to your tables, to speed up the joins.  Adding the query and sample data would help your question.

Comment: Try reading through [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), particularly part "*If you're asking about query performance*" and then edit your question so we can actually help you.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Some JOINs are terrible for performance.  (EAV schema design is notorious.)

Some JOINs have very little effect on performance.  (Simple normalization is very common.)

Let's talk about specific queries.  Provide such a `SELECT`, together with the `SHOW CREATE TABLEs` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`